# Retrofit, hace el login correctamente pero se cierra la app

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, retrofit

**Bueno pues eso, intentando que cambie de activity pulsando el botón, entra en el success correctamente pero se cierra la aplicación con el Intent ahí. ¿Me he dejado algo atrás?**

**La llamada a Retrofit**

```
mLoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(ApiInterface.ENDPOINT)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .build();

                ApiInterface service = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);

                //Call<LoginResponse> repos = service.doLogin("admin@admin.com", "password");

                Call<LoginResponse> repos = service.doLogin("admin@admin.com", "password");

                repos.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {
                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Intent ...
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListaCursosActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            // Preferencias ...
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response.body().getMensaje(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Log.i("EII", "Login: "+response.body());
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login incorrecto. CODE" + response.code(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<LoginResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "on Failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

**Logcat**

```
03-28 22:31:29.091 28534-28534/com.classroommanager W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40f139a8)
03-28 22:31:29.096 28534-28534/com.classroommanager E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.classroommanager/com.classroommanager.CursosFragment}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1624)
                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1423)
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3388)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:50)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:79)
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3349)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:859)
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3584)
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3552)
                                                                          at com.classroommanager.MainActivity$1$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:62)
                                                                          at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:68)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
                                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: ¿Puedes publicar el error que te muestra y señalar a que parte del código te redirecciona  si le das click al error?

Comment: Pues ese es el caso, o la consola de Android ha cambiado o no publica errores, publico lo que me sale de todas formas

Comment: @Jose si no agregar el mensaje desplegado en el LogCat es casi imposible determinar el problema y tu pregunta puede ser considerada como demasiado amplia. **Si deseas desarrollar en Android es indispensable el uso del LogCat**.

Comment: Tomando de referencia la imagen que anexas, da click en donde dice "Android Monitor" donde se encuentra el Android, ahí podrás ver el LogCat  ᕦ ´• ᴥ •` ᕥ

Comment: gracias, me había confundido de pantalla, ya he obtenido el logcat

Comment: El problema es porque tu activity no la has declarado en tu manifest, por eso te arroja el "ActivityNotFoundException", solo agregala como una actividad más.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No tienes declarada tu actividad en el manifest, eso lo dice aca:

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit
>   activity class
>   {com.classroommanager/com.classroommanager.CursosFragment}; have you
>   declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?